# NoClassDefFoundError in mapActivity

Tags: android

i have this error in my map app.do you know what is wrong?i have checked and the package is right in my .java files and also i have put the uses-libraries of google maps into my  application tag in the manifest.xml..please help,im trying hours to solve it..

Comment: i had asked for this later in the day:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853152/force-down-error-in-mapview

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Make sure you have put in

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

inside your `<application></application>` tags.

Comment: Also make sure to use a virtual/real device that contains the Google APIs.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/01/18/using-google-maps-in-your-android-app/

Check the part about the API key if you are migrating your project to another development environment.

ps I am really surprised how people can pinpoint such a naive answer (as above) correct.

Comment: That's because the person that wrote the "naive" answer properly read the question ;).  An incorrect API key does not result in a NoClassDefFoundError.  Not referencing the library from the manifest does.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to post the relevant code.

Reading your question carefully, if you really put the uses-permission tag inside the application node, that is wrong. You should put permissions outside of it, but still inside the manifest node, so the end of your manifest file may look something like this:

```
 </application>
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Eclipse may put them before the start of the `<application>` tag too, which is also fine.